# VBA conversion to VB.Net File Binary Read

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm attempting to convert some `VBA` to `VB.Net`. I have not used `VB.Net` much as I prefer using `C#`, however due to the amount of code I need to convert I'm coding a `VB.Net dll`, which I can use as a reference in the `C#` application.

I have the following `VBA` code and need to be able to produce the same in `VB.Net`

```
Open FileName For Binary Access Read As #1
Get #1, , customType
```

Where ***customType*** is a user-defined data type. I have replicated the required *types* as *structures* in `VB.net`, however I'm not sure where to start in reproducing this code for `VB.Net`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

### Update 1:

```
FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Binary)
FileGet(1, customStruct)
```

The above seems to be somewhat working, however I get the following exception when the custom structure has a item defined as an array.

e.g,

```
Public Structure CustomStruct
    Dim FileType() As Byte
End Structure
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Non-negative number required.

I have initialized the dimensions via,

```
ReDim customStruct.FileType(7)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/binaryreader-vbnet). It should give you all the information you need to read a binary file in vb.net

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this. I've recently found `FileOpen` and `FileGet`, which hopefully is the equivalent in VB.net. Reading is not so much the problem, however assigning the binary read to the custom structure is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after a lot of trial and error, the below works,

`FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Binary)
 FileGet(1, customStruct)`

In regards to the other issue, the array must be declared as fixed in the structure, even if it is initialized prior to being used

```
<VBFixedArray(2)> Dim FileType() As Byte
```

Josh